# Figure out exact Oracle version

Tags: oracle, solaris-10

I've Solaris 10 with some Oracle on it .

How to find exactly, with maximum accuracy what Oracle version installed +  what 64 or 32 bit this Oracle supported ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you connect and execute a query?

If so:

select * from v$version where banner like ‘Oracle%’;

Comment: I'm happy you did it :)